# VisualSVN Server - Auto Lock

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

So, I'm trying to set up an SVN server to manage binary files. As a result merging is impossible, so we want to use a lock-modify-unlock work ethic to avoid these problems.

At this point I'm willing to move to other version control software. I've picked SVN because it's logically quite easy to deal with (it's on the server, nothing else matters), but I'm by no means stuck with it.

I've looked around but most information is old. So I'm wondering if it's possible to have the SVN server apply the need-lock property to files automatically? I know I can do it on a per client basis, I'm looking for a server side solution.

It's appears to be possible, but as a completely new arrival to SVN it's hard to interpret some of the terminology, and what I can edit without VisualSVN overwriting it etc.

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you **must** to:

- [read about](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config)
- [understand](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops)
- use

Repository Dictated Configuration, implemented in Subversion 1.8 (thus - all server and client versions must be at least 1.8)

You **can not**, from that moment, use plain `svnadmin create` or *only* VisualSVN Server's tool for creating repositories, because you have to apply some `svn ps` to the root of fresh repository (task, not supported nor CLI-version nor VisualSVN Server nor TSVN /but we have at least VisualSVN Server's Devs and @stefan here, you can ask to have such feature added/)